# How email templates should be stored in the repository?

Tags: email, salesforcedx, deployment, email-template, metadata

I have a file "default" which has:

- applications
- aura
- classes
- contentassets
  etc
  I added a new directory "EmailTemplate" and I added files "email0.email" and "email0.email-meta.xml" but I have error:

> An object 'undefined' of type EmailTemplate was named in package.xml but was not found in zipped directory

I added in package.xml this code:

```
<members>EmailTemplate</members>
```

But I still got the same error.

What should I do in such situation?

Creating an email template manually and removing it from the repository works but is there any other, better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have added your email template names to the package.xml too along with the metadata type

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">        
    <types>
        <members>FolderUniqueName/email0</members>
        <name>EmailTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

FolderUniqueName is your unique name of the folder. This should pull the email templates you have into a directory named **email/FolderUniqueName**.